# Omnet++ parsing xml file

Tags: xml, parsing, simulation, omnet++

I have example where it s used

void readConfig1(cXMLElement *rootelement)

to access xml data. My question is how omnet parse xml file. Clearly this is function calles readConfig1 that declare pointer rootelement. But I am more interested in structure of xml object that this pointer refer to.

Comment: This is Libxml2 type from dependency library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMNeT++ uses LibXML2 internally for parsing, but should absolutely check the API documentation for OMNeT++ if you are interested in details how classes should be used:

https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cXMLElement.html